# Qt WARNING: QObject::connect: No such signal QApplication::screenRemoved(QScreen *)

Tags: linux, qt, debian, virtualbox, gnome-terminal

The following error occurs when running my virtual box 5.1 from terminal in Debian 8 and this error when I close virtualbox:

Qt WARNING: QObject::disconnect: No such signal QApplication::screenRemoved(QScreen *)

What should I do?

Comment: Is this even a programming question?

Comment: I'm encountering the same problem on `Qt 5.15.2`. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "screenRemoved" is a singnal from "QGuiApplication".

And "QApplication" iherits "QGuiApplication".

It is all good. But this method is there from Qt5.4 version.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#screenRemoved

Please check your QT version. May be it is bit older.